# How to convert Siemens (.JT) or CGR File into GLFT/GLB with ASPOSE?

Tags: aspose, gltf, catia

I am quite new to THREE.js, working on LAN based application to make .JT files view-able to users without any additional license. I have some how managed to convert .JT into .WRL using catia, but it has file sizelimit. so again i converted it into .GLB but still file size is too big.

However i couldnt fine any way to convert CGR to .GLB

if somehow we can manage JT to GLB conversion with limited options. we will be able to manage it .

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "has file sizelimit"?
JT is in general a visualization format, so that converting JT to glTF would be re-packing triangulation from one to another file. And as JT file defines compression, while glTF does not (without extensions), converted file will be expectedly larger.
Preparing the file for web would require more pre-processing - like simplification and decimation, which are usually provided with non-free tools (like CAD Processor and similar).